# Передача модели между контролеррами

Tags: asp.net

Есть модель

```
public class Model
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Age { get; set; }
}
```

И два контролера

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.id = 1;
        model.Name = "Andre";
        model.Age = 1.3;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "My", new { data = model });
    }
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    // GET: My
    public ActionResult Index(Model data)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

В MyController приходит data=null. А как-же мне передать модель между контролеррами?

Comment: просто `model` передай

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index", "My", new { model }); - все равно получаю null

Comment: зачем ты делаешь `new { model }`? Передай просто `model`

Comment: Ну да, правильно. new создает новую переменную. А как тут пометить правильный ответ?

Comment: если ты разобрался - можешь сам ответить на вопрос, указав что делал не так и как исправил.

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index", "My",  model ); - так правильно

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "добавить свой ответ" можешь нажать ее и расписать в чем была проблема и как ты ее исправил

Answer (score 0):

return RedirectToAction("Index", "My", model ); - так правильно